# Copy / paste in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint

What makes copy/paste work in LinuxMint, is there a default clipboard manager installed? In other distros this doesn't work if you close one application and paste in other.

Answer (score 1):

Linut Mint 7 uses [Parcellite Clipboard Manager](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/). Other distros usually don't use clipboard managers by default.

Comment: In Linux Mint 12 parcellite is not installed by default, so it's not active.

Comment: What other distroy did you test? And what do you mean bei close one app and paste in other? Closing the source-app does not affect the clipboard itself (in any distro)

Comment: Ubuntu ( a bit older version) and Fedora 16. If you copy a text in firefox, close firefox, open chrome and paste in chrome, is not working.